# Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'

Tags: java, android

There's a code:

```
MainActivity.java:

package asus.example.com.notes1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();
        setIntent("This is example test");
        return true;
    }

    private void setIntent(String text) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_create_order:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, OrderActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return true;

        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program, I get the error:

> org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'. at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:
>   Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1 path $

What's the matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue because Android Studio instant run, disable instant and run again.
Go to Android Studio Settings or Preferences (for MAC) -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run.

Then deselect the "Enable Instant Run" checkbox at the top.

Comment: Is the issue known by the Android Studio developers? Is there any other workaround than disabling it?